# Definition of maximal order of element of group

Tags: abstract-algebra

My textbook makes reference to an element of a group of "maximal order". Is this just an element of greatest possible order? I can't find a definition in the literature, and I know that in general maximal and maximum elements are not equivalent.

Edit: one may find an example of the usage here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Abelian_Group_of_Prime-power_Order_is_Product_of_Cyclic_Groups

Comment: Yes. That's how it is typically called. "element of maximal order"="element of greatest possible order"

Comment: Note that in some (infinite) groups, there may not be an element of maximal order.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how this maximality gets used in your proof in the textbook?

Comment: If one uses the notation $|x|$ for the order of an element $x$ of a group $G$, then an element $x$ of maximal order (in a finite group) is one such that $|a| \leq |x|$, for all $a \in G$. Things get a bit murkier when discussing infinite groups.